# Prototype cell from storyboard not creating UILabels, etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329334/objects-inside-my-custom-uitableviewcell-created-with-storyboard-are-nil).
My custom prototype cells designed in Interface Builder using storyboards have all the internal objects set to nil (not created), so when I try to assign values to them, they remain blank.

I am using Xcode 4.6.2, and running the code in the 6.1 iPhone simulator. Here is what I've done:

- designed a prototype cell in interface builder with the necessary fields.
- created a subclass of UITableViewCell for this custom cell in code, and then set the cell in interface builder to this type.
- control-dragged the fields into the .h file, which set up the objects (UILabels, etc) for me. I set the identifier of the cell to "serverNameCell"
- set the datasource & delegate of the table to the Viewcontroller that the table is in.
- associated the table with a table object in the ViewControler

At the moment, the table displays with the correct number of sections & rows, but the values of the cell are not being set.

This is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` code:

```
NewServerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"serverNameCell"];
```

I always get back a cell, and the memory location seems to be ok for a valid object.

But when I try to `cell.name.text = [thisServer name];` I find that the `cell.name` label is always nil.
There are no crashes - but my fields are not being set.

I have checked a million times that the identifier is ok - it is!
I have gone through the Apple documentation for custom cells from a storyboard - but still get this frustrating issue..

Anyone else had this, and resolved it?

Comment: If you log cell, does it say it's a NewServerCell, not a UITableViewCell?

Comment: @rdelmar: Yep, it's a NewServerCell, but all of it's properties (and that of it's ancester UITableViewCell) are nil

Comment: Hmmm.... this kind of question is hard to diagnose, as everything you  said you did sounds correct. Did you use either of the register methods (for registering a class or nib)? If the cell is made in the storyboard, you shouldn't use either of those. Is there anything in your custom cell code other than IBOutlets?

Comment: @rdelmar: I tried with and without the `registerClass forCellReuseIdentifier` - now without, and no dice. Nothing at all apart from the (connected) IBOutlets

Comment: If there's somewhere you could post the project, I'll look at it, but as I said, these kinds of problems are hard to diagnose without actually seeing the project.

Comment: i had the same issue. embarrassingly enough, it turns out after  removing and re-adding the class file to the project i forgot to re-connect the outlets in the class to the storyboard...

Answer (score 24):

I had this exact problem today with Xcode 5's storyboard. After pulling almost all my remaining hair out, I noticed I was calling this in `viewDidLoad`:

`[self.tableView registerClass:[SwitchTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Setting"];`

Whoops! This line is unnecessary when using prototype cells in storyboards. The storyboard automatically configures this for me. `SwitchTableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Setting" forIndexPath:indexPath];` works just fine without calling `registerClass::` explicitly.

The question still remains of *why* calling `registerClass::` causes some outlets to not be connected.

Comment: I was also pulling all my hair out in desperation. Have you found out why it registerClass causes some outlets to not be connected? It happened to me with Swift.

Comment: This certainly worked for me, @DefenestrationDay you should mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I'm used to designing custom table cells using separate xibs so I brought that line of code along to my storyboard-based cells.

Comment: I would have voted 10 times for this answer if I could!

Comment: now is 2018 and I still have the same issue with XCode 9/Swift 4 and iOS 11. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An easy workaround for this problem is to tag the UILabel in the prototype and manipulate it with:

```
UILabel* label = [cell viewWithTag:cellTag];
label.text = [thisServer name]
```

Comment: Weird - there is _definitely_ a label with the tag I used, but when I cast it back to a label in the cellForRowAtIndexPath - it's nil..

Comment: The Label is still nil. And it should be. I do not know why storyboard will not initialize the label inside the cell

Comment: are you calling the register method? That would cause you properties to be nil

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most obviously missed reason (**I do it all the time!**):

***Did you set the delegate and datasource of your tableview to the controller? (i.e. self)***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have already got a fix for this issue. Anyways since I do not see a straight forward answer to your issue, I am writing this down.

From my experience in the case of using custom Prototype cell in storyboards, provide the indexPath as well. Use the following method:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead of this code:

```
NewServerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"serverNameCell"];
```

Changing this will readily fix this issue. You will see all hooked up labels and image views with their values visible on the tableview.

Answer (score 1):

Scratched my head way too hard on this one. Ended up being that I was declaring my IBOutlets with `retain` instead of `strong` in my CustomUITableViewCell.h file. I guess I need to research more into memory management.

Wrong:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView  *preview;
```

Correct:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView  *preview;
```

Answer (score 1):

check how you`re initializing your TableViewController. 
I had the same problem, then I figured that I was not referencing my TableViewController appropriately.

So i had to change my code before the "pushViewController".

Instead of : `[[TableViewController alloc]init]`
use : `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:yourTableViewIdentifier]`

and dont forget to REMOVE any code registering cell classes for your tableview like : `[self.tableView registerClass:[SwitchTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Setting"];`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Some stuff to try:

It sounds like you know what you're doing but I'll mention the obvious just to remind you.  Make sure the "name" property is set to IBOutlet.

- In IB you can set the class type for files owner, Set this to
  your custom class.
- Just for sake of troubleshooting take out the dequeue stuff
  temporarily and try it.
- Try another property name other than "name" I dont believe "name"
  exists in baseclass though.

I've run into similar things like this before, it's probably something simple.

Comment: The OP is using a storyboard, there is no File's Owner object in a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same problem (labels were `nil` in the cell).

My remedy was to remove an `initWithCoder` method that I "accidentally" added to the table view while trying out other stuff. This method is called when the cell gets initiated from the storyboard. If you overwrite it and don't take care of initiating all labels inside of it yourself you will end up with `nil` labels.

So, as one potential error for this symptom: Check for presence of this method.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [self init];
    return self;
}
```